# Unable to update core data object correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Below is my update method

```
-(void)updateData:(NSString *)doctorName hospitalName:(NSString *)hospitalName emailAdd:(NSString *)emailAdd phoneNum:(NSString *)phoneNum mobileNum:(NSString *)mobileNum
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DoctorInfo" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSString *query = doctorName;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(doctorName = %@)", query];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSAsynchronousFetchResult *storeResult = [delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:request error:&error];
    NSArray *result = storeResult.finalResult;

    DoctorInfo *firstResult = [result firstObject];
    firstResult.doctorName = doctorName;
    firstResult.hospitalName = hospitalName;
    firstResult.emailAdd = emailAdd;
    firstResult.phoneNumber = phoneNum;
    firstResult.mobileNumber = mobileNum;

    if (![delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't edit: %@", error);
    }
}
```

I am able to update all the variables except `doctorName`. I think it could be due to this line of code:

```
NSString *query = doctorName;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(doctorName = %@)", query];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
```

How should I modify this method so that I can update the doctorName as well ?

Comment: What do you want to change the doctor name to? The only value you have in the code is the value that you used to search for the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a name that's different than the one already there. Right now you're re-using the existing name, setting `doctorName` to he same value it has.

Let's say you call this method with a `doctorName` argument of "Jane Smith". When the following lines run, you will fetch only existing records where the doctor name is already "Jane Smith":

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(doctorName = %@)", query];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Then you do the following. At this point `doctorName` is still "Jane Smith", and the `doctorName` on `firstResult` is *also* "Jane Smith". You're making the assignment with the same value that's already there:

```
firstResult.doctorName = doctorName;
```

Your code doesn't have a different doctor name anywhere. You're updating the value, sort of, but you're updating it to be the same value it already has.

If you want to change the name, you need to have a different name to use. How to do this depends on how your app works. Maybe you would add an argument to this method called `newDoctorName`, containing the new name. Then you'd change the line above to read

```
firstResult.doctorName = newDoctorName;
```

Or maybe you would change your predicate to use something other than `doctorName`. I don't know what-- again, it depends on how your app works.